# Weird compilation issue

Tags: java, compiler-errors

The following class will not compile:

```java
public class Thing {

    public static <T> T foo(java.util.function.Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return supplier.get();
    }

    public static <T> T bar(java.util.function.Function<Integer, T> function) {
        return function.apply(42);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(foo(() -> "hello")); // 1
        System.out.println(bar(any -> "hello")); // 2 !!!
        System.out.println(bar((Integer any) -> "hello")); // 3
        System.out.println(Thing.<String>bar(any -> "hello")); // 4
        println(bar(any -> "hello")); // 5
    }

    private static void println(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

The issue is on line [2] in the `main()` method (all other lines are fine):

```
[ERROR] .../Thing.java:[13,19] reference to println is ambiguous
    both method println(char[]) in java.io.PrintStream and method println(java.lang.String) in java.io.PrintStream match
[ERROR] .../Thing.java:[13,31] incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    lower bounds: char[],java.lang.Object
    lower bounds: java.lang.String
```

I don't understand why the compiler thinks there is an ambiguity on the return type of `bar()` (`char[]` or `String`) and can't decide which flavor of `println()` method should be used. On line [1], it can infer that the return type of `foo()` is `String` and on line [3], I don't understand how specifying the type of `any` (`Integer`) helps because it could not be anything else given the signature of the `bar()` method.

Comment: That code works perfectly fine for me on jdk 1.8

Comment: I tried it with an online compiler (https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/) and it fails on JDK 1.8... Are you using Eclipse or some other compiler?

Comment: using Eclipse yes

Comment: I see it fail on IntelliJ with 19ea. Odd. Maybe one of those overload resolution clashes with type inference bugs?

Comment: Eclipse has its own (incremental) compiler which is sometimes smarter wrt type inference. But this code fails with standard (openjdk-based) compilers and under IntelliJ.

Comment: Yeah, when manually compiling, I get the same error

Comment: The JDK compiler is known to cut corners on certain inference cases. Other than a few more workarounds, I would suggest reporting it to the JDK maintainers.

Comment: Although seeing similar cases, they will most likely just bounce it back saying Eclipse is wrong.

Comment: @akarnokd I think Eclipse is wrong according to the JLS. Perhaps I should be a JDK maintainer? (lol)

Comment: @Sweeper :) I'm pretty sure they wouldn't let you improve things because muh compilation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the implicitly typed lambda `any -> "hello"` is not [pertinent to applicability](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2), and so it is practically ignored when determining what type the call `bar(any -> "hello")` should be (See [Invocation Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2.1) sections of the JLS), in order to select the correct `println` call.

The justification can be found from the first link:

> The meaning of an implicitly typed lambda expression or an inexact method reference expression is sufficiently vague prior to resolving a target type that arguments containing these expressions are not considered pertinent to applicability; they are simply ignored (except for their expected arity) until overload resolution is finished.

So other than the fact that we are passing it to `System.out.println`, there are practically no bounds on the return type of `bar` at all - it could be any reference type. The compiler tries to infer which overload we are trying to call using the rules in that second link above, but `println(String)` and `println(char[])` both seem like valid overloads!

The reasons why the other lines work are:

- `System.out.println(foo(() -> "hello"));`
- `System.out.println(bar((Integer any) -> "hello"));`

  these lambdas are all pertinent to applicability, because they are [explicitly typed lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.1) (though this rule has some exceptions). Note that a lambda with no parameters counts as an explicitly typed lambda.
- `System.out.println(Thing.<String>bar(any -> "hello"));`

  Since you have provided the type parameter of `bar`, the compiler does not need to determine it using type inference. It can now be trivially determined that `bar` returns `String`, so you must be calling `println(String)`.
- `println(bar(any -> "hello"));`

  There is only one overload of `println` to pick, so even though we can't know that `bar` returns `String` from the lambda, we can still do it by seeing that the `bar` call is being passed to `println(String)`.

I recommend that you have a look at the list of expressions that are not pertinent to applicability and play around with them :)